# How do i restrict direct access (from browser) to a folder but allow access to image files inside it..?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having problem with htaccess. what I want to do is when a user accessed my folder named `images` from a browser I want to restrict it, but when accessing image files inside it, I want to display the image in the browser. Tried the following code but no success.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

So, can you please suggest something?

Comment: put these blocks in reverse order?

Comment: tried by reversing the order, but still no success, sorry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply add an empty index.html. This will stop the direct access to that folder.

Another solution is that:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Enter the above code into htaccess. That will produce a 403 HTTP Status code on folder access, but will allow you do share the content !

Answer (score 4):

Turn indexes off in the [options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options).

```
Options -Indexes
```